# Problems with hexagon images css?

Tags: html, css, image, avatar

I am trying to make avatar as a hexagon, I have found a css snippet for doing this, but it only worked for non-square images:

```css
.hexagon {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hexagon-in1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon-in2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: contain;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hexagon hexagon1">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image:url('https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQG-vLQJr3J3zg/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=cXNxHCDmX7A_e_LGk75XIbL-eVc7VYdHQfSFH39r3Qo')"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="hexagon hexagon1">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image:url('https://poemesurleprophete.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/la-seule-force.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

The problem as you can see, with images where width equals height it is not exactly a hexagon, I tried to set the `background-size` to `cover`, it worked but part of the image is being cropped. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: use clip-path instead: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you so much, i did not know about `clip-path` property before, it is much more elegant solution, at the end I used it.

Answer (score 1):

it's because the hexagon-in2 is rectangular, put in his css class:

```
width:72%;
margin:0 14%;
background-size:cover;
```

It will look like:

```css
.hexagon {
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.hexagon-in1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon-in2 {
  width: 72%;
  margin: 0 14%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-60deg);
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
}
.hexagon1 {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="hexagon hexagon1">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image:url('https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQG-vLQJr3J3zg/company-logo_200_200/0?e=2159024400&v=beta&t=cXNxHCDmX7A_e_LGk75XIbL-eVc7VYdHQfSFH39r3Qo')"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <br />
 <div class="hexagon hexagon1">
    <div class="hexagon-in1">
      <div class="hexagon-in2" style="background-image:url('https://poemesurleprophete.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/la-seule-force.jpg')"></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

hope it will help